# Function not returning all database rows

Tags: php, json, database, codeigniter

I have this function in Code igniter PHP where I am trying to get all rows from the database that match a input value.
How should I change the code to get all rows that match my search criteria?

Thank you

Model search function:

```
function findquestion($searchvalue){

        $this->db->where('answer1', $searchvalue);
        $res = $this->db->get('questions');
        $count = $res->num_rows();

        if($res->num_rows()==0){
            return "...";
        }
        $moviearray = $res->row_array();
        return $moviearray;
    }
```

Controller Function:

```
public function getdatabasedata()
    {

        if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET')
        {
            $year = $this->input->get('searchvalue');
            if($year != ''){
                $movie = $this->adminmodel->findquestion($year);
                echo json_encode($movie);
            } 
        }
}
```

When I look at Postman to check what the JSON object holds, this is what I get. But in fact I have three more rows in my database that match my search criteria.

```
{
  "id": "10",
  "question": "test questions",
  "image": "test image",
  "answer1": "answer1",
  "answer2": "answer2",
  "answer3": "answer3",
  "answer4": "answer4"
}
```

Comment: You need to loop over all results in `$res`.

Comment: @jeroen and store them in array?

Comment: Yes, and send that back from the method.

Comment: @jeroen is it correct if I encode the array in JSON in the other function?

Comment: Use $this->db->like('answer1', $searchvalue); instead  of $this->db->where('answer1', $searchvalue);

Answer (score 0):

```
function findquestion($searchvalue){
```

> 1) define array.

```
        $data = array(); 
        $this->db->where('answer1', $searchvalue);
        $res = $this->db->get('questions');


        if($res->num_rows()==0){
            return "...";
        }
```

> 2) loop trough results and store in array.

```
        foreach ($res->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = array(
                    'id' => $row->id,
                    'question'  => $row->question,
                    'image'  => $row->image,
                    'answer1'  => $row->answer1,
                    'answer2'  => $row->answer2,
                    'answer3'  => $row->answer3,
                    'answer4'  => $row->answer4
                );
            }
        //$moviearray = $res->row_array();
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: You can just json_encode the whole result_array, save yourself lines in the code.